# Why does Bootstrap 4 use private methods in es6 classes?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, class, ecmascript-6, private

I was looking inside the source code of Bootstrap 4, and I discovered they're using es6 classes coupled with some revealing module pattern of some sort.

Here is a simplified example of code taken from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/modal.js).

```
const Modal = (($) => {


  const NAME                         = 'modal'
  const VERSION                      = '4.0.0-alpha.3'
  ...

  const Default = {
    ...
  }


  class Modal {

    constructor(element, config) {
      this._config              = this._getConfig(config)
      this._element             = element
      ...
    }


    // public

    toggle(relatedTarget) {
      ...
    }

    show(relatedTarget) {
      ...
    }

    hide(event) {
      ...
    }

    dispose() {
      ...
    }


    // private

    _getConfig(config) {
      ...
    }

    _showElement(relatedTarget) {
      ...
    }

    _enforceFocus() {
      ...
    }

    _setEscapeEvent() {
      ...
    }

    _setResizeEvent() {
      ...
    }

  }

  return Modal

})(jQuery)

export default Modal
```

This would result in every method or property being exposed, including the private ones. However, this does not happen in the final product. For example, something like `$('#myModal').modal('_getConfig')` would not work. What is happening?

Comment: Probably `modal` does check whether the name begins with an underscore…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only adding one function to the jQuery prototype `_jQueryInterface`:

```
  $.fn[NAME]             = Modal._jQueryInterface
  $.fn[NAME].Constructor = Modal
  $.fn[NAME].noConflict  = function () {
    $.fn[NAME] = JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT
    return Modal._jQueryInterface
  }

  return Modal

})(jQuery)
```

If you look at the code of `_jQueryInterface` you'll see:

```
static _jQueryInterface(config, relatedTarget) {
  return this.each(function () {
    let data    = $(this).data(DATA_KEY)
    let _config = $.extend(
      {},
      Modal.Default,
      $(this).data(),
      typeof config === 'object' && config
    )

    if (!data) {
      data = new Modal(this, _config)
      $(this).data(DATA_KEY, data)
    }

    if (typeof config === 'string') {
      if (data[config] === undefined) {
        throw new Error(`No method named "${config}"`)
      }
      data[config](relatedTarget)
    } else if (_config.show) {
      data.show(relatedTarget)
    }
  })
}
```

If we look closely, you'll see that the instance of the class Modal is being saved as `data`:

```
    if (!data) {
      data = new Modal(this, _config)
      $(this).data(DATA_KEY, data)
    }
```

You can access it in the same fashion the script does it (but only after creating it for the first time):

```
let data    = $(this).data(DATA_KEY)
```

`DATA_KEY` is `bs.modal`

*Edit:*

```
$('#myModal').modal('_getConfig');
```

The function `_getConfig` is actually being called, it's just that function is returning the jQuery object not whatever the result of `_getConfig` is.

Comment: Correct, so basically those private methods aren't actually private